# Show training and validation accuracy in TensorFlow using same graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a TensorFlow model, and one part of this model evaluates the accuracy. The `accuracy` is just another node in the tensorflow graph, that takes in `logits` and `labels`.

When I want to plot the training accuracy, this is simple: I have something like:

```
tf.scalar_summary("Training Accuracy", accuracy)
tf.scalar_summary("SomethingElse", foo)
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/me/mydir/', graph=sess.graph)
```

Then, during my training loop, I have something like:

```
for n in xrange(1000):
  ...
  summary, ..., ... = sess.run([summary_op, ..., ...], feed_dict)
  writer.add_summary(summary, n)
  ...
```

Also inside that for loop, every say, 100 iterations, I want to evaluate the **validation** accuracy. I have a separate feed_dict for this, and I am able to evaluate the validation accuracy very nicely in python.

However, here is my problem: I want to make another *summary for the validation accuracy*, by using the `accuracy` node. I am not clear on how to do this though. Since I have the `accuracy` node it makes sense that I should be able to re-use it, but I am unsure how to do this exactly, such that I can also get the validation accuracy written out as a separate scalar_summary...

How might this be possible?

Comment: For some other solutions, I had a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146614/tensorboard-plot-training-and-validation-losses-on-the-same-graph).

Comment: This may answer your questions (without setting two summary dirs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471563/logging-training-and-validation-loss-in-tensorboard

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can reuse the the accuracy node but you need to use two different SummaryWriters, one for the training runs and one for the test data. Also you have to assign the scalar summary for accuracy to a variable.

```
accuracy_summary = tf.scalar_summary("Training Accuracy", accuracy)
tf.scalar_summary("SomethingElse", foo)
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
summaries_dir = '/me/mydir/'
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(summaries_dir + '/train', sess.graph)
test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(summaries_dir + '/test')
```

Then in your training loop you have the normal training and record your summaries with the train_writer. In addition you run the graph on the test set each 100th iteration and record only the accuracy summary with the test_writer.

```
# Record train set summaries, and train
summary, _ = sess.run([summary_op, train_step], feed_dict=...)
train_writer.add_summary(summary, n)
if n % 100 == 0:  # Record summaries and test-set accuracy
  summary, acc = sess.run([accuracy_summary, accuracy], feed_dict=...)
  test_writer.add_summary(summary, n)
  print('Accuracy at step %s: %s' % (n, acc))
```

You can then point TensorBoard to the parent directory (summaries_dir) and it will load both data sets.

This can be also found in the TensorFlow HowTo's https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html

Comment: Thanks wih let me try this out...will report back.

Comment: Ok so I think this is the issue: The "summary_op" contains the merged summaries of some things. However I just want the "summary" for the validation_error... does that make sense? Like if I pass in "summary_op" again inside the n % 100 loop and get the "summary" out, then it seems like it would "run" ALL the summaries. (All the ones that were merged). But I just want the accuracy node to be run...

Comment: Also, why doesnt the test_writer have a "sess.graph" in it?

Comment: The summary_op will write all summaries to the test file. I adjusted the code, now only the accuracy summary is recorded for test.

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks for validating! This also answers a related question I had on overlaying the plots, which it now does automatically. Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: The test_writer doesn't have the graph because it#

Comment: Never press enter while commenting ;) The test_writer doesn't have the graph because it's the same graph and then tensorboard would display it twice. Displaying different "runs" (here it's the same run but different data) is the only way to overlay plots. When you modify your network it would be useful to display both graphs.

Comment: I have a question regarding this which I am trying to solve. 
Suppose validation data set is big suppose has more than 2000 samples. Now, I can not feed the dictionary of all the samples. What I want to do is pass the validation set in batches of size 50, collect all the accuracy in an array, average those accuracies and then plot that on tensorboard.

Comment: It shows two equal graphs, each have two plot. How to remove one of these repetitions?

Comment: Could it be possible to merge only 2 operations(e.g. The test accuracy and test cost) into one test summary node? I'm looking for some statement similar to tf.merge_all_summaries() but with specific summary nodes.

Answer (score 7):

To run the same operation but get summaries with different feed_dict data, simply attach two summary ops to that op. Say you want to run accuracy op on both validation and test data and want to get summaries for both:

```
validation_acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar('validation_accuracy', accuracy)  # intended to run on validation set
test_acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar('test_accuracy', accuracy)  # intended to run on test set
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # do your thing
    # ...
    # accuracy op just needs labels y_ and input x to compute logits 
    validation_summary_str = sess.run(validation_acc_summary, feed_dict=feed_dict={x: mnist.validation.images,y_: mnist.validation.labels})
    test_summary_str = sess.run(test_acc_summary, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,y_: mnist.test.labels})

    # assuming you have a tf.summary.FileWriter setup
    file_writer.add_summary(validation_summary_str)
    file_writer.add_summary(test_summary_str)
```

Also remember you can always pull raw (scalar) data out of the protobuff summary_str like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568675/parsing-summary-str-byte-string-evaluated-on-tensorflow-summary-object) and do your own logging.